# PackageInstallationReceiver can't remove temporary apk file

Tags: android

A friend got an error on his HTC Desire trying to install an app. He uses eclipse for installing.

The error from LogCat:

```
E/PackageInstallationReceiver( 244): Remove /data/local/tmp/my.package.apk Fail! W/System.err( 244): java.io.IOException: Error running exec().
```

I used adb shell to see whats inside this tmp folder. And there was no such apk. So I renamed another, but the error stays which means, that he never really tries to delete this apk, right?

The same code runs fine on the emulator and my Nexus One. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the .apk with the same name like the error to this error path
then I started the application again and I got the same error but it works

...